# TTreeView checkbox loses "selected" state after change scale on screen

Tags: delphi, vcl

As in topic. When I change scale of screen, example from 100% to 125% in windows(screen setting) my TTreeView Repaints and loses checked/selected state in checkboxes.

Delphi 11 and 12 - the same behaviour.
VCL

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean checked or selected? It is a more severe problem if the checked state is lost or confused. Also, crucially important: VCL or FMX? Delphi version?

Comment: Under VCL, if the scale change causes the TreeView to recreate its `HWND`, it will save and recreate the nodes when the new `HWND` becomes available. That process saves and restores both checked and selected states.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I added some information in description

Comment: I think it looks like a Delphi VCL bug and i should report this.

Answer (score 1):

I asked on another website and someone after confirmed my bug report gave me suggestion which looks like works! Of course it needs to be tested but for me it helped.

```
const
  CM_BASE = $B000;
  CM_RECREATEWND = CM_BASE + 51;
type
  TTreeView = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView)
  protected
     procedure CMRecreateWnd(var Message: TMessage); message CM_RECREATEWND;
  end;

  implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTreeView.CMRecreateWnd(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result:= 0;
end;
```